# DocumentRoot entry is not working

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Can anyone please tell me why the below entry is not working and it says file not found at `/www.abc.com/login/index.php`. Just for info - "www.abc.com" is the folder name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/websites/www.abc.com/
 ServerName 192.168.01.01
 <Directory "/srv/www/websites/www.abc.com/">
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

This is the entry in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file.

I am also getting this error (found in my error logs):

> File does not exist: /srv/www/websites/www.abc.com/www.abc.com

Comment: for clarification your accessing: `http://www.example.com/login/index.php` ?

Comment: Yes. i am accessing http://www.example.com/login/index.php and i enven tried accessing http://www.example.com/www.abc.com/login/index.php as well. Both the cases same response.

Comment: I think you should be using the URL `http://domain.com/login/index.php` - you have repeated the `www.abc.com` twice. Once in the doc root, once in the directory part of the URL.

Comment: If that does not work try taking the trailing slashes off the folders in the vhost config and restarting.